# How do I isolate just Keywords from exif_read_data function?

Tags: html, image, metadata

After using the example from [this](http://php.net/manual/en/function.exif-read-data.php) page which talks about `exif_read_data`:

```
<?php
echo "images/image.jpg:<br />\n";
$exif = exif_read_data('images/image.jpg', 'IFD0');
echo $exif===false ? "No header data found.<br />\n" : "Image contains headers<br />\n";

$exif = exif_read_data('images/image.jpg', 0, true);
echo "images/image.jpg:<br />\n";
foreach ($exif as $key => $section) {
    foreach ($section as $name => $val) {
        echo "$key.$name: $val<br />\n";
    }
}
?>
```

I got the following result:

```
images/image.jpg:
Image contains headers
images/image.jpg:
FILE.FileName: image.jpg
FILE.FileDateTime: 1477597739
FILE.FileSize: 65777
FILE.FileType: 2
FILE.MimeType: image/jpeg
FILE.SectionsFound: ANY_TAG, IFD0, EXIF, WINXP
COMPUTED.html: width="640" height="480"
COMPUTED.Height: 480
COMPUTED.Width: 640
COMPUTED.IsColor: 1
COMPUTED.ByteOrderMotorola: 1
IFD0.Orientation: 1
IFD0.Exif_IFD_Pointer: 2122
IFD0.Keywords: Tag_1;Tag_2;Tag_3 <--- info I need
IFD0.UndefinedTag:0xEA1C: �
EXIF.ExifVersion: 0221
EXIF.ColorSpace: 65535
EXIF.UndefinedTag:0xEA1C: �
WINXP.Keywords: ?????????????????
```

So I just now need to know how to isolate the IFD0.Keywords: Tag_1;Tag_2;Tag_3 part of the results.

How would be able to do this?

---

(Orginal question was about how to extract meta data from an image and display it on a webpage, which I managed to do, the question evolved to something else. Placing original question details below)

When using Dreamweaver, if I "Insert>Image" it will add the code

```
<img src="images/Image.jpg" width="400" height="757" />
```

in automatically, along with the width and height.

I'd like to add in the image metadata automatically too (it obviously won't be part of the `<img>` tag, it would be output as just text.)

Something like

```
<img src="images/Image.jpg" width="400" height="757" />
<p> Tags: something; something; something </p>
```

I would suppose a script would have to be written that would target a folder and pull the metadata out of all the images. I don't even know if that is possible.

How would I be able to do this?

Comment: Of course you could, but "how" depends entirely on when you want to do it, and under what environment(s).

Comment: Offline, whenever I want to by  manually targetting folders

Comment: I'm using exif_read_data and I've managed to get it work based on the example from http://php.net/manual/en/function.exif-read-data.php, but its not showing the tags. Any help?

Comment: Any code? (And please not in comments, edit the question.)